# get $http service and call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to get the $http service in angular js and then call get function on it inside my custom asyncAction function call. There's no html involved (bootstrap???)

Edit: Can put some dummy html to make it work to trigger the controller something

I've a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/smartdev101/bdmkvr6g/

```
    asyncAction: function(resultFunction, faultFunction) {

    $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/angular")
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
        console.log(data);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
},
```

Some progress - updated fiddle, added, some html tag to make it work, but

can someone find me a way without having to insert markup in my code and even triggering `AttendeeProxyController` myself without this `ng-controller` tag ???? I'd prefer full manual boot and controller trigger process.

OR lateral thinking... I don't event need this controller, it's there so that I can get access of $http purely just in javascript without html?

```
<span id="attendeeProxyController" ng-controller="AttndeeProxyController"></span>
```

Comment: You might consider adding some further context to your question. My assumption is a lot of Javascript developers are not familiar w/PureMVC. I used to use PureMVC in Actionscript, and frankly, it seems like you wouldn't need to use PureMVC in an AngularJS application (unless you're adding Angular to an existing PureMVC app). In AngularJS, you inject things like `$http` into your Angular controllers, services, etc. What is unclear (to me) is how PureMVC works in Javascript <-- If you can clarify that, it might help to find you solution.

Comment: irrespective of framework in use, it has to do something with manually bootstrapping and getting the $http, it could be a framework like Backbone, it's a framework agnostic question.

Comment: Great clarification. I may have went overboard, but I think that your original question was not very clear until you added your latest comment ;)

Comment: do you know a way that can help get rid of this `span` html tag and manually trigger the controller too???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> OR lateral thinking... I don't event need this controller, it's there so that I can get access of $http purely just in javascript without html?

Yes, while I recommend against it it's possible to do

```
var $http = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$http");
// use $http here
```

This will get you a direc reference to $http which you can use. However it's against the Angular way of dependency injection, it'll generally produce harder to test and harder to reason about code if you're not careful.

Comment: you're right but I've a manageable and modular architecture built around angular using frameworks and libraries like Backbone or puremvc. Thanks @Benjamin for the answer, it works :)

Comment: `var $routeProvider = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$routeProvider");` possible to get this???

Answer (score 0):

Like @Benjamin said, you can use the invoke to auto inject dependency to you function.

```
var $injector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
$injector.invoke(function($http){
    $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/angular").success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

[Here is $injector document.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector)